# Protect values after form submission codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

What I am trying to do is show the form validation errors if there are any and prepopulcate the form.

**View**

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['project_id']; ?>"  name="project_id" id="project_id">
<input type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('name'); ?>"  name="name" id="name">
```

**Controller**

```
$validation_rules = $this->access_m->rules;
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($validation_rules);
        if($this->form_validation->run()){
            // process the form

        }else{


            $data= array(
                    'subview'=>'access/access',
                );
            $this->load->view('layout', $data, FALSE);
        }
```

Now what the problem is, I can prepopulate the value for the name, but how do I prepopulate the value for the `project_id` field. Since the value for the field is extracted from the `GET` method, is there any way I can pass it back to the view so that I can use it again.

I could use a redirect and add the project ID to the url as `example.com/access?project_id=23` but then I would loose the values to prepopulate to the rest of the form fields.

Any solutions ??

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)). User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: @Quentin Can you elaborate. Because I am new to codeigniter and dont know much about it.

Comment: There is nothing CodeIgniter specific about this problem. It is an issue with any kind of server side scripting involving HTML. The link elaborates.

Comment: Any input (GET, POST) is checked for XSS (if enabled).  http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/security.html

Answer (score 0):

Create method that accepts parameters `example.ufo/controller/accept/<id>`

From now on you don't need hidden field, your id is accesible within the method more info is here http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#passinguri

example:

```
<?php
class User extends CI_Controller {

    public function accesible( $id = false) {
        //necessary checks, is id valid? is it numeric? is id in database?... does user have permission to work with element with this ID?

        echo $id;
    }
}
?>
```